# If I install ros noetic from source, will I be able to install noetic packages?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-noetic

Because my computer could only run Ubuntu 22.04, it seems like I could only install ros noetic from source. But I have a little concern, if I want to install any package in the future, do I need to build every packages from source? Or will the `sudo apt install ros-packages` command still work once I successfully install ros noetic?

Thank you!

---

Thank you @Marcus for answering my question! I don't why I cannot comment, so I will write it up here.
I did not know the docker would be so convenient! But I saw there might be some performance issue when using docker. I am going to use gazebo, will there be any performance issue if I run gazebo with docker?

Thanks again!

Comment: You seem to have two accounts: [1](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/38383/ben) and [2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/users/40166/ben), as shown by this [suggested edit](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23874). The reason that you can not comment is that you logged in with a different account. You can merge the accounts, please see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)?

Answer (score 1):

When you install ROS Noetic from source on Ubuntu 22.04, you'll likely need to install future ROS packages from source as well, because the `sudo apt install` method is mainly for packages built for Ubuntu 20.04. Some packages might still work if you install them with `sudo apt install`, but for the best compatibility, especially with newer or more complex packages, building from source will be your go-to method.

A best alternative to avoid compatibility issues is using Docker! Why don't you download a Noetic Docker image ? You will use Ros noetic normally on Ubuntu 22.04 as you as if it were running on Ubuntu 20.04. This method bypass a any  OS compatibility issues

```
docker pull ros:noetic-robot
```